# Does the iOS 9 simulator run on High Sierra?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9, macos-high-sierra

I appreticate any now would give me the exact idea of minimum Xcode version and simulators woking on High Sierra.

Comment: not sure if you had the same issue. Launching the Simulator directly I got an error even though I had the latest XCode. I had to run XCode once, it said "installing extras" or something like that and then the Simulator started running

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Xcode 9 it and the Simulator that ships with it run on 10.12.6 and 10.13.

If you mean the iOS 9 Simulator Runtime it also runs on 10.13.